# Branch into trunk merging and vice versa

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

Generally, after creating a branch, I still can develop further on on the trunk AND the branch. This leads to following use cases for me:

### Use cases

**A. branch was created from trunk and changes were done to the trunk AND the branch**

- *Let's say, trunk has rev. 1000 and brunch has rev. 1001 at the beginning*
- *Let's say, trunk develoment stopped at rev. 1010 and branch development at rev. 1015*

  1. How to get the changes from the branch into the trunk?
  2. How to get partial changes from the trunk to the branch?

**B. branch was created from a previous branch**

- *Let's say, trunk has rev. 1000 and the first branch has rev. 1001 at the beginning*
- *Afterwards trunk has rev. 1010 and first branch has rev. 1015*
- *we create a second branch from the first branch and get rev. 1016*
- *Let's say we develop on at the trunk AND the second branch. And the second branch development stops at rev. 1020 and the branch development at rev. 1025*

  1. How to get all changes from the branch back to the trunk?
  2. How to get partial changes from the trunk to the branch

Following options are available:

- Merge Type 1: Merge a range of revisions
- Merge Type 2: Reintegrate a branch
- Merge Type 3: Merge two different trees

Now, generally I know how to do it, so I answer my question partially to make sure I'm doing it right:

### Solutions

**Solution for A1:**

merge type 2. Merge with trunk (all revisions > 1001)

**Solution for A2:**

I don't know how to achieve that... Only with comparing in the resource browser and merging temporarly and copying the results to my local files manually... Is that possible somehow else?

**Solution for B1:**

Must be in two steps??? Is following solution correct? And the easiest one? Seems to be quiet much work if not done regulary...

1. use merge type 2 to merge first branch back to the trunk (all revisions > 1001 and < 1015
2. use merge type 2 to merge second branch back to the trunk (all revisions > 1016 and < 1020

**Solution for B2:**

same as for A2